# How to explain Genome, Genes, RNA and protein in one figure to non-biologist?

Tags: genomes

I have a presentation to do where non-biologist are attending. In order to introduce a little bit my work I have to do a quick summary on genomes. So what is a genome, a gene, an mRNA and a protein. And the best would be to have that in one figure, an easy to understand. I found this : http://dnamismatch.com/Test/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Genes-and-genomes.png

Anyone knows other resources ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd go with using an analogy - e.g. The genome is a cookbook, each recipe is a gene, the cook is the mRNA and the product is a protein (perhaps not entirely analogous but you get the picture) - you have to find something that can adequately explain all of the four parts in one coherent and correct example. Personally I think the figure you've shown is poor (aesthetically and only roughly illustrates what genomes and genes are, not proteins or mrna)

Comment: Some info about the topic of the talk might be helpful in guiding answers here

Comment: the topic : retrovirus and cancer . So I have to introduce genomes and genes in the case of retroviral integration

Comment: There can be different ways and giving analogies would work. What is the educational background of the audience and how much time do you have for your presentation?

Comment: the audience consists of both biologists and no scientist at all.